# AWS switch lambda DR

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi i have lambdas deployed in us-east-1 and planning to setup DR lambdas in us-west-2, all my lambdas are running as cron and based on eventbridge events. I want to disable the event trigger in us-west-2 by default and need to find a way to toggle(active/deactivate triggers) between us-east-1 and west2. I can do with calling AWS API's or SDK from my local. Is there any centralised AWS service available 24/7 ( not region specific ) to handle this case ?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a rogue suggestion but if you want to stick on AWS you could use LAmbda@Edge functions. They're distributed globally so you'd be able to make an api request, and hit whichever one you target.

If you setup a lambda in your system to respond to a URL, AWS Route 53 has healthcheckers which source globally so if it notices your lambda failing, it'll trigger globally that your route is down. That could trigger an alarm in the *other* region to activate that.

Alternatively setup a google or cloudflare function doing the same thing (polling healthcheck to your main region).